# Twitter bootstrap , ternary operator .

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i was going through the twitter bootstrap source code and as a Jquery newbie , i am a bit confused with the following line :

```
var options = typeof option == 'object' && option
```

button.js source code : [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js#L16)

now i understand what typeof checks for and i also what && does ,

heres my understanding , typeof checks for a type of a given variable and && is something i have usually seen in if statements , something like this :

```
if( a === "ok" && b=true ){ console.log('condition passed'); }
```

but somehow i am not able to understand this line in the button.js plugin , it totally baffles me .

its this line in the source code : [The Line](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js#L78)

is it some kind of a if condition or something ?

i know this might be a relatively easy question for a forum like SO , but i am not able to put the peices togeather by myself .

Thanks .

Gautam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means: if `option` is an object then `option` should be assigned to `options`. If that is not the case, then `options` will be `false`.

The original statement is:

```
var options = typeof option == 'object' && object;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
var options = typeof option == 'object' ? object : false;
```

We have won seven characters :)

It is very common to exploit the logical operations (and the *truthy-falsy* properties) of JavaScript, because it provides some concise and highly usable patterns.

PS: I recommend reading [this book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/), it has a nice overview on JavaScript design patterns.

Comment: If you understand the concepts, and do not try to write Java code in JavaScript, I do not think its overly complicated. This is one of the most used JavaScript patterns AFAIK.

Comment: What does Java have to do with it? The statement simply looks like it returns a boolean, I would never have realised it was returning an object in some instances! Unfortunately this is just the state of javascript i guess! awful!

Comment: Well you could write this too, this is equivalent: `typeof option == 'object' ? option : false`

Comment: Ahh, interesting! That seems much more readable to me but im wondering if it's simply due to its familiarity to c#! Thanks very much!

Comment: Exactly, thats why I mentioned with Java. A lot of people have pain with JavaScript, because their *assumptions* based on their background. (I myself included sometimes, as I am a Java dev mostly)

Comment: @meskobalazs Thanks for your answer , i'll just read through it . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof option == 'object' && option
```

If the variable option was defined as object type and has a value assigned to itself, then the previous line will return the option.

```
var options =
```

Will take option or false as result.